# Launching image not displayed in iOS 3.1.3

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm deploying a calculator and I want it to be compatible with iOS 3.x. I'm almost finishing and have a little problem. I setted a launching image in info.plist file. The launch image is shown in the simulator but not in the device. Anyone can figure what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your launch image must be named 'Default.png' or one of the other similar file names discussed [in this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5).

Does your solution work on other iOS versions?

Comment: Tahnks James. The problem was on the name of the file.